# How do I run lots of regex replacements on all text in html elements using ES6/7?

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I'm looking to write a client side script that will run multiple regexes against a page's text nodes using the fanciest and newest JavaScript ES6/ES7 methods. How do I do it?

Comment: @gyre I'm answering a question on Facebook that was asked by a friend, if you must know. he wrote this `var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
var element = elements[i];

for (var j = 0; j < element.childNodes.length; j++) {
var node = element.childNodes[j];

if (node.nodeType === 3) {
var text = node.nodeValue;
var replacedText = text.replace(/Old Text/gi, 'New Text');

if (replacedText !== text) {
element.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(replacedText), node);
}
}
}
}`

Comment: Just trying to show him how to improve it, do what he wants, and make the contribution useful to others. I have plenty of badges. thanks for the question =)

Comment: Ah; interesting policy SO has on self-answering.  A cool answer nonetheless! And yes, I figured you must have had some logical motive given that you are already so well-decorated.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this.. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/EvanCarroll/09qea27u/3/)

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
const replaceDict = { 'New Text': /Old Text/gi, 'what': /this/gi };

for ( const e1 of elements ) {
  if (e1.parentNode.nodeName != 'BODY') {
    continue;
  }
  Array
    .from(e1.childNodes)
    .filter( e => e.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE )
    .forEach( e2 => {
      let replaceText = e2.nodeValue;
      for ( let [k,v] of Object.entries(replaceDict) ) {
        replaceText = replaceText.replace( v, k );
      }
      if ( replaceText != e2.nodeValue ) {
       console.log(`Replacing ${e2.nodeValue} with ${replaceText}`);
       e2.nodeValue = replaceText;
      }
    } )
  ;
}
```

```html
  <p>
   this is a Old Text test
  </p>
  <p>
   this is a Old Text test Old Text
  </p>
```

You can also just stick to the `Array.from()` syntax if preferred,

```
const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
const replaceDict = { 'New Text': /Old Text/gi, 'what': /this/gi };

Array.from(elements)
  .filter( e => e.parentNode.nodeName === 'BODY' )
  .forEach( e => {

    Array.from(e.childNodes)
      .filter( e => e.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE )
      .forEach( e2 => {
        let replaceText = e2.nodeValue;
        for ( let [k,v] of Object.entries(replaceDict) ) {
          replaceText = replaceText.replace( v, k );
        }
        if ( replaceText != e2.nodeValue ) {
          console.log(`Replacing ${e2.nodeValue} with ${replaceText}`);
          e2.nodeValue = replaceText;
        }
      } );

  } );
```

Here we have a replaceDict that compiles the regexes. We iterate over the elements using an ES6 iterator, and then we convert the dom's childNodes into an Array and use `.filter` and then `.forEach` to make the replacements. We update the textnode just once regardless of how many different replacement patterns we issue on the node. We `console.log` for debugging purposes.

Comment: Two points: 1) Can I suggest `nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE`? `3` is not very intuitive. 2) `getElementsByTagName("*")` could return anything: `<style>` or `<script>` tags included. You may want to filter these depending on use case